# New blender 3.0 and EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

what are the improvements for EEVEE in the new Blender 3.0?

is there any evolution in shader nodes?
like for example : node bevel , pointness and AO , etc?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can find highlights of this information in the [Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/EEVEE).

Very little has changed in EEVEE, according to the notes:

- Attribute Node

  > Custom mesh attributes (generated for example by Geometry Nodes) are now accessible via the Attribute node.
- Wavelength Node

  > Support for wavelength node has been added to EEVEE, earlier it was Cycles only. It is now similar to Blackbody node, which uses a sampled color map internally.
- Performance

  > Performance when editing huge mesh is improved. Changes in many areas are made resulting in an improvement of 2-3 times depending on the executed operation.

You can find a detailed list of the performance changes [here](https://developer.blender.org/T88550)